# Connecting to SQL Server with Unity

Tags: asp.net, unity-game-engine

I am trying to connect to SQL Server with unity. I have done this many times before but not on unity. It says completed **but the data is not inserted**. I have already added the `System.Data.dll` to my project assets. My goal is to insert user inputs from inputfield into the database.

Output:

> SocketException: The operation completed successfully.

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class DbConn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField username;
    public InputField score;
    public Text ftext;
    public string connectionstring;

   // button action
   public void Onclick()
   {
       // SQL Server connection
       connectionstring = @"Data Source = servername; Initial  Catalog = NewtonGame; User ID = username; Password = [password];";
       string sql = "insert into Playerscore(username, score) values (@username, @score); ";

       using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
       using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon))
       {
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", score.text);

           sqlCon.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it says "completed"? Did you try debugging the code? Did you add logging statements to see if it finishes?

Comment: This is the output I got in unity console `SocketException: The operation completed successfully. ` I cant debug unity code on Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you add logging statements to see if the code finishes or even gets reached?